# Port in Jetty server (Equinox OSGi )

Tags: jetty, osgi, equinox

Good morning, I am deploying a Web Application into Jetty Server embebed into Equinox OSGi. Still, i works in port 8080, but I need to run two different servers. Then, a conflict between ports is launched. I would like to change port number in one of servers. Could someone help me please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try those system properties:

> jetty.port=xxxx - Jetty specific property
>
> org.osgi.service.http.port=xxxx - OSGi HTTP Service property

Comment: What if you specify both properties? For example if my environment is running with two webservers? Which property will jetty use?

Comment: 1. for jetty you can use fragment bundle with configuration. you can configure 1+ connectors with different ports

2. for OSGi HTTP service you have to use OSGI ConfigurationAdmin for the service to define which port(s) will be used

Answer (score 0):

if you run in eclipse, you can try put this in your VM argument

```
-Dorg.osgi.service.http.port=9090
```